# How can I make h2 style text be two colors on tumblr?

Tags: html, colors, tumblr

I'm writing on my tumblr blog and I'm trying to make this text in h2 style be two colors. This is what I have:

```
<h2 style="padding: 20px 20px 30px; margin-top: 2px; text-align: center; position: relative;">Harley Quinn</h2>
```

I want the "Harley" to be red and the "Quinn" to be black. I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried this, and it works while I'm still editing the page, but as soon as I click save and leave, the [span style] part goes away.

```
<h2 style="padding: 20px 20px 30px; margin-top: 2px; text-align: center; position: relative;"><span style="color:#9C0000">Harley</span> Quinn</h2>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend to try inspect the element after you saved your changes. Take a look https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles

Comment: could you provide some URL adress? Thank you

Comment: Don't style the h2 put two spans inside the h2 and style them individually

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it does not work please provide me your URL adress maybe there is a problem somewhere else :)

```
<h2 style="padding: 20px 20px 30px; margin-top: 2px; text-align: center; position: 
relative;"><span style="color:#9C0000!important">Harley</span> <span 
style="color:#000000!important">Quinn</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created two methods which work similarly, but in order to abstract them I've separated the inline styles into simple class names. However I don't recommend using these class names, this is purely for illustrative purposes.

HTML

```
<h2 class="red">Harley <span class="black">Quin</span></h2>

<h2><span class="red">Harley</span> Quin</h2>
```

CSS (for both)

```
.black {
    color: #000;
}

.red {
    color: #f00;
}
```

As black is a default font colour, the second method uses less markup.

JSFIDDLE example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/m4p0Lbjh/)